# Check for path existence between two points with obstacles in between

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of circles with their center coordinates & radius

```
[(x,y,r) ...]
```

and two lines parallel to the x-axis

```
ymin = m
ymax = n
```

I want to find out if a particle is able to travel from -infinity to infinity within the space strictly between ymin & ymax & does not collide with any of the circles (i.e. it cannot go over ymin and ymax and through the circles)

References

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVhuU.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/FngxF.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHgQz.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsrer.jpg

Here is my approach

```
1. Sort circles by x
2. Create a list of circle groups such that, 
  - Any pair of circles between two different groups never overlap &
  - A group cannot have a forest of circles i.e. they are connected one way or the other if you follow the overlapping circles in them
3. Go through each group and if in any group, the min(g'y) <= ymin & max(g'y) >= ymax then return false. true if no such group satisfies the condition
```

Unfortunately my approach to step 2 was `N^2` and I can't think of any other solution

```python
def is_a_path(list_of_circles, y1, y2):
    list_of_circles.sort()
    overlapping_circles_groups = [];
    for current_circle in list_of_circles:
        found = False
        for overlapping_circle_group in overlapping_circles_groups:
            for circle_in_group in overlapping_circle_group:
                if is_overlap(current_circle, circle_in_group):
                    found = True
                    overlapping_circle_group.add(current_circle)
                    break
        if found == False:
            overlapping_circles_groups.append({current_circle})
                
    ## assuming circle group list is complete
    
    for group in overlapping_circles_groups:
        ymin = min([y - z for (x,y,z) in group])
        ymax = max([y + z for (x,y,z) in group])
        if ymin <= y1 and ymax >= y2:
            return False
    return True
```

Sorry for the non-idiomatic python code (not an expert in it)

Comment: Interesting! Where did you find this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going good. As you said it, you need to optimize step 2.

**Why is step 2 O(N^2)?**

[image]

As shown in the above image, red circle doesn't overlap with green circle, but blue circle does overlap with red. This scenario makes it O(N^2) where N is the number of circles. Did sorting the list of circles by x coordinate help you? Can you try to get over this?

**Weak Hint:** Can you trade off some space for better time complexity?

Stop here, think. May be you'll figure this out yourself. If not, come back and read further.

.

.

.

.

Intentional gap to avoid reading the solution unintentionally.

.

.

.

.

**Strong Hint:** Can you try using diameters instead of the coordinates of the center?

Stop here, think. May be you'll figure this out yourself. If not, come back and read further.

.

.

.

.

Intentional gap to avoid reading the solution unintentionally.

.

.

.

.

**Solution:** It should be straight forward with the above hint.

1. Just convert the list of circles to list of x coordinate of diameters like <x_start_1, x_end_1, circle_index_1>, <x_start_2, x_end_2, circle_index_2>, ...
2. Sort by x_start
3. Check for overlapping diameters using x_start and x_end. If the diameters overlap, the circles overlap too, right? NO! Check if circles really overlap. That is why we stored the circle_index in step 1 above. circle_index is the index of the circle in the given input list of circles <(x,y,r),..>. See the image below for more understanding.

[image]

4. From step 3, you know group of overlapping circles. As you did in your post, check if they block the particle from traveling to infinity.

Step 2 makes this solution `O(NlogN)`. Rest of the steps are `O(N)`. In fact, you can do everything in one pass after step 2.

**Follow up:**
Do you see any edge case? Will the above algorithm handle it? Check the image below.

[image]

As a simple follow up, I want you to take care of circles having same x_start and x_end.

Thanks! I loved solving this problem.

Comment: Yes, I did get the hint that this is somewhat of an overlapping interval problem but working with center coordinates wasn't really working out for some cases. Frankly I'm Aw'd after looking at your solution. xstart,xend was the way to go. Great insight!

Comment: @FaizHalde I am glad you liked it. That was a nice question. So, I am curious about the source of this question.

Comment: It was part of an interview I had yesterday

Comment: @FaizHalde: I too felt so. Good question for 40 mins to think and code flawlessly especially all the edge cases. I would rate as higher medium or hard if not seen before.

Comment: I think this is still O(n^2) because all diameters might overlap and you still have to check all overlapping diameters.

Comment: @maraca: We check each diameter only once in a sorted order.

Comment: So if you have circles a, b, c, d already sorted and all overlapping then you just check if a-b, b-c, c-d ?  Like this you will miss if a overlaps d which is possible without overlapping b and c.

Comment: @maraca: Sorting by x_start will take care of it. See the very first diagram in my post. Blue circle has its x_start before green circle if it wants to overlap with the red circle. That is the very core of making it `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: Yes I see that, unfortunately it is not true. The scenario I described is possible even with this kind of sorting. You have to consider that it is 2d

Comment: E.g. move the blue circle 1mm to the right in the last picture. So the order is clearly r, g, b. Now you detect r overlaps g, but g doesn't overlap b so there is a way? This would be wrong if you only compare with the next circle in order. And if you don't do that, i.e. check with all potentially overlapping circles then the algo is correct but still O(n^2)

Comment: actually yes, step 2 has a worst case scenario which makes it N^2 :) just becauwe we have sorted by x doesn't mean we only need to check circle[i] with circle[i-1]. I think we may have to apply binary search on x or y or both x and y to find the range of circles that are potential candidates. just an idea

Comment: @maraca: Awesome! Such edge cases make this question hard for an interview setting. A raw approach fix for the case that you brought up is another NlogN for y axis which will help us keep the total solution NlogN. Let us think if a better solution could be come up. Thanks! Its night here. I'll be back on this tomorrow. Though, keep your brilliant inputs coming.

Comment: @FaizHalde: Did interviewer discuss anything on this question during or after the interview about time complexity expectations?

Comment: he did mention my solution is "but this is N^2" but he let me continue. typically solutions are less important but the discussions/thought process is valued more. he did like my psuedocode (i.e. my approach)

Comment: @FaizHalde: Okay. Though, can't agree on `typically solutions are less important`. It depends on many other things.

Comment: I mean obviously solutions largely drifting from correctness is certainly not tolerated. I meant in terms of performance, clean code, discussions happening in the interview. They play a much larger role

Comment: I think interval trees solves this problem. still trying to work things out